# icc does not recognize preprocessor directive "defined" in OpenBLAS

Tags: preprocessor, icc, openblas

I built OpenBLAS (commit 2c7392f07bb802) with gcc 6.2.0 without a problem. If I try to use icc (using `make CC=icc FC=ifort`) the build process fails with `dsytrd_sb2st.F(484): #error: #if: syntax error`.

The associated line in this file is

```
#if defined(_OPENMP) &&  _OPENMP >= 201307L
```

Exchanging `#if defined` by `#ifdef` solves this problem. Why does icc fail on the `defined` directive?

Comment: Which icc version was this?

Comment: Also, that looks like a Fortran source file. I wonder if the L is causing a problem.

Comment: I used icc/ifort 17.0.1 20161005